# gulp, build multiple projects

Tags: gulp, commonjs

I have a Gulp build process that runs through roughly 10 tasks, including browserify and watch. It currently builds a common-bundle.js, and common-libs.js. It uses browser-sync to give me sub-second rebuilds.

Now I want to also build a project that depends on the common project. I want to retain the live rebuilds of both common and this project so that I could work on both of them at the same time. I want to keep the build process itself as DRY as possible and reuse the tasks i created to build common.

For example, a sample task:

```
var config = require('../config');
gulp.task('styles', function () {
  return gulp.src(config.styles.src) // if i could tell it to get config elsewhere...
  ...
```

I can't pass a parameter into each task to tell it, go run the task but use:

```
var config = require('../config').common;
```

vs.

```
var config = require('../config').projectA;
```

I don't think tasks can take parameters.

Is there a different way to structure this?
git/gist link would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For now I am trying this approach - each task js file has 2 tasks defined, but at least the logic of the task is reused. I still wish for something cleaner.

./gulp/task/style.js:

```
function styles(config){
   return gulp.src(config.styles.src)
      ...
   }
}
gulp.task('styles', function () {
   styles(config.common);
});
gulp.task('stylesProject1', function () {
   styles(config.project1);
});
```

devTask.js:

```
runSequence(['styles', 'stylesProject1], 'watch', callback);
```